# Convert a pandas dataframe to model instances in Django?

Tags: postgresql, dataframe

I got a dataframe that returns the following data:

```
   ticker                     stock  exchange   earnings_yield    roic      sum_rank
0  24STOR       24Storage AB (publ)  ST         0.0000             0.0000     26186
1     AAK            AAK AB (publ.)  ST         0.0420             0.1720      7978
2     ABB                   ABB Ltd  ST         0.0020             0.0460     16804
3     AUR  Auriant Mining AB (publ)  ST         0.1600             0.3270      2245
4  BETS-B                Betsson AB  ST         0.1020             0.2120      3955
```

It's roughly 17000 rows and I need to find an efficient way of converting each row to its own model instance.

My `Stock` model looks like this:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    objects = BulkUpdateOrCreateQuerySet.as_manager()

    stock = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    earnings_yield = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)
    roic = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=4)
    roic_rank = models.IntegerField()
    ey_rank = models.IntegerField()
    sum_rank = models.IntegerField()
```

At first, I was just thinking of converting the dataframe to a dictionary:

```
ranked_companies = df.to_dict(orient="records")
```

and then looping through that huge dictionary:

```
stocks_to_upsert = []
for company in ranked_companies:
    stocks_to_upsert.append(
        Stock(
            ticker=company["ticker"],
            stock=company["stock"],
            exchange=Exchange.objects.get(exchange_code=company["exchange__exchange_code"]),
            earnings_yield=company["earnings_yield"],
            roic=company["roic"],
            roic_rank=company["roic_rank"],
            ey_rank=company["ey_rank"],
            sum_rank=company["sum_rank"],
        )
    )
```

However, my Heroku dyno is screaming that I'm exceeding the memory boundaries and I assume its because it's highly inefficient storing such as a big dictionary in memory. So, is there a better way of saving the dataframe as model instances? (And later upserting them).

Should I bypass djangos ORM altogether and do a raw sql statement? I noticed that pandas has a `to.sql` function. Not sure how to proceed though.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

looping through dataset is always a bad idea (apart from exceptions).
specially when databases are designed to load/fetch data as sets.
I would use pandas to insert/fetch directly data into database as a set. so you don't need to loop through every single row:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
connEngine = create_engine('<connectionstring>');
conn = connEn.connect();
dbconnection = 
try:
    df.to_sql("TableName",dbconnection,if_exists='append');
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    conn.close();
```

Comment: @erikvm is your stock table as it shown in the model ?

Comment: Yes, (and already populated with data, so ideally I'd need some form of bulk upsert)